# Overview of the different Parallel programming methods

Tags: r, parallel-processing, computer-science

I'm learning how to use parallel programming (specifically in R, but I'm trying to make this question as general as possible). There are many different libraries that work with it, and understanding their differences is hard without knowing the computer science terms used in their descriptions.

I identified some attributes that define these categories, such as: fine-grained and coarse-grained, explicit and implicit, levels of parallelism (bit-level etc.), classes of parallel computers (multi-core computing, grid computing, etc.), and what I call "methods" (I will explain what I mean by that later).

**First question:** is that list complete? Or there are other relevant attributes that define categories of parallel programing?

- Secondary question: for each attribute, what are the pros and cons of the different options? When to use each option?

About the "methods": I saw materials talking about *socket* and *forking*; other talking about *Parallel Virtual Machine* (PVM) and *Message Passing Interface* (MPI) (and another option called "NWS"); and some other specific methods like *Hadoop*/*map-reduce* and *futures* (from R's "future" package).

**Second question:** I don't understand some of them, and I'm not sure if it makes sense to join them in this list that I called (parallel processing) "methods". Also, are there other "methods" that I left out?

- Secondary question: what are the pros and cons of each of these methods, and when is it better to use each?

**Third question:** in light of this categorization and the discussion on the pros and cons of each category, how can we make an overview of the parallel computing libraries in R?

My post might be too broad, and ask too much at once, so I'll answer it with what I found until now, and maybe you can correct it/add to it in your own answer. The points that I feel that are most lacking is understanding the pros/cons of each "method", and of each R package.

Answer (score 1):

OP here. I can't answer the "is that list complete?" part of the questions, but here are the explanations to each attribute and the pros and cons of each option. Just to reiterate that I'm new to this subject and might write something false/misleading.

## Categories

### Fine-grained, coarse-grained, and embarrassing parallelism ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing#Fine-grained,_coarse-grained,_and_embarrassing_parallelism)):

**Attribute:** how often their subtasks need to synchronize or communicate with each other.

- Fine-grained parallelism: if its subtasks must communicate many times per second;
- Coarse-grained parallelism if they do not communicate many times per second;
- Embarrassing parallelism if they rarely or never have to communicate.

**When to use each:** self-explanatory

### Explicit and implicit parallelism ([ref](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/i/implicit-parallelism.htm#:%7E:text=If%20you%20had%20to%20write,for%20you%20behind%20the%20scenes)):

**Attribute:** the need to write code that directly instructs the computer to parallelize

- Explicit: needs it
- Implicit: automatically detects a task that needs parallelism

**When to use each:** Parallel computing might introduce too much complexity when working with tasks, such that implicitly parallelism can lead to inefficiencies in some cases.

### Types/levels of parallelism ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing#Types_of_parallelism)):

**Attribute:** the code level where parallelism happens.

- Bit-level, instruction-level, task and data-level, superword-level

**When to use each:** From what i understood, in the most common statistics/R applications, we use task and data-level, thus I didn't searched about when to use the other ones.

### Classes of parallel computers ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing#Classes_of_parallel_computers))

**Attribute:** the level at which the hardware supports parallelism

- Multi-core computing, Symmetric multiprocessing, Distributed computing, Cluster computing, Massively parallel computing, Grid computing, Specialized parallel computers.

**When to use each:** From what i understood, unless you have a really big task that needs several/external computers working, you can use multi-core computing (using only your own machine).

### Parallelism "method":

**Attribute:** different methods (there probably is a better word for this).

[This post](https://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ejerrick/courses/stat701/notes/parallel.html) makes a distinction between *socket* approach (launches a new version the code on each core) and *forking* approach (copies the entire current version of your project on each core). Forking isn't supported by Windows.

[This post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-parallel-virtual-machine-pvm-and-message-passing-interface-mpi/) makes a difference between Parallel Virtual Machine (PVM) and Message Passing Interface (MPI) (which I couldn't quite understand). Apparently, there is another option called "NWS", which I couldn't find information about.

[This CRAN task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) contains a list of packages, grouped by topic, that are useful for high-performance computing in R. It refers to a method called "Hadoop" which was built upon "map-reduce", and to the "future" package, that uses "futures" to introduce parallelism to R.

**When to use each:** While in socket each node is unique (avoiding cross-contamination), and runs on any system, forking is faster and allows to access your entire workspace in each process. I couldn't find information to talk about PVM, MPI, and NWS; and didn't get in depth into Hadoop and futures, so there is alot of space to contribute to this paragraph.

## R packages

The CRAN task view is a great reference to this. It separates which packages deal with explicit/implicit parallel processing, most of which work with multicore-processing (while also pointing out some that do grid-processing). It points to a specific group of packages that use Hadoop, and other groups of parallel processing tools and specific applications. As they're more common, I'll list the explicit parallelism ones. Package names inside parenthesis are upgrades to the listed package.

- `rpvm` (no longer actively maintained): PVM dedicated;
- `Rmpi` (`pdbMPI`): MPI dedicated;
- `snow` (`snowFT`, `snowfall`): works with PVM, MPI, NWS and socket, but not forking;
- `parallel` (`parallelly`) was built upon `multicore` (forking focused and no longer actively maintained) and `snow`, and it is in base R;
- `future` (`future.apply` and `furrr`): "parallel evaluations via abstraction of futures"
- `foreach`: needs a "parallel backend", which can be `doMPI` (using `Rmpi`), `doMC` (using `multicore`), doSNOW (using `snow`), doPararell (using `parallel`), and doFuture (using `future`)
- `RHIPE`, `rmr`, `segue`, and `RProtoBuf`: use Hadoop and other map-reduce techniques.

I also didn't get in depth into how each package works, and there is room to add pros/cons and when to use each.